# Convert String to date in Crystal Report Formula

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have string in database column called `ConsignDate` in the format `1980-09-04`. How can I convert this string into a date in `DD-MM-YYYY` format?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: sql sever 2005 and data type nvarchar(255)

Comment: One possibility might be to convert this to a `DATETIME` in the SQL query you're using to retrieve the data - something like `CAST(ConsignDate AS DATETIME)`

Comment: need to show only mm-dd-yyyy this string in report only

Comment: there are so many ways to do this.also you are not clear.You can create formula for this feild.in formula use split function to split the string and concatenate it back.

Comment: Use totext function in crystal reports

Comment: Simple Matter Of Programming.   Parse the string to get the parts you want, and piece them together in the order you want.   It's tedious, but not difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your original format was yyyy-mm-dd (and that they were always 4 digit years and always 2 digit month and day)

```
right(ConsignDate,2)+"-"+mid(ConsignDate,6,2)+"-"+left(ConsignDate,4)
```